# Python Regular expression to match if any number appears more than a certain amount of times

Tags: python, regex

I'm in need of a regular expression for python that is able to match all strings where **any** number appears a certain amount of times (4 times in a 5 digit number is my desired result in this example).

For example, consider this list:

```
["11211", "23424", "22323", "99991", "88988", "11122"]
```

I would like a regEx that returns

```
["11211", "99991", "88988"]
```

because in these three cases, there is a digit that appears more than 4 times in the number.

I am not even sure if this is easily doable with just one single regEx, apart from hardcoding the digits from 0-9, which does not seem to be an elegant solution.

Here is a regEx that matches four 1's in a list of 5 number strings:

```
four1 = re.compile(".*1.*1.*1.*1.*")
```

But is there a more elegant solution than these two to not only search for four 1's, but four of any kind, as long as they are four times the same number?

```
four1 = re.compile("(.*1.*1.*1.*1.*")|(.*2.*2.*2.*2.*")| ...
```

or

```
four1 = re.compile(".*1.*1.*1.*1.*")
four2 = re.compile(".*2.*2.*2.*2.*")
...
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group and a back-reference:

```
(\d)(?:\d*?\1){3}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tXMCoe/2/)

**RegEx Description:**

- `(\d)`: Match a single digit and capture in group #1
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\d*?`: Match 0 or more digits
  - `\1`: Back-reference to capture group #1 to make sure we match repeating digits of capture group #1
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `{3}`: Match 3 instances of above non-capture group

**Code:**

```
import re

arr = ["11211", "23424", "22323", "99991", "88988", "11122"]
reg = re.compile(r'(\d)(?:\d*?\1){3}')
for s in arr:
    if reg.search(s):
        print s
```

**output:**

```
11211
99991
88988
```